# Python: Threading within MultiProcess Function runs in the same core as the multiprocess one or the parent one?

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing, python-multithreading

```
def multiprocess_function():
   run = 0   
   while run == 0:
     for i in the range(100):

        #This will initiate 100 threads
        threading.Thread(target=sum, args=(i,0))

     time.sleep(10)

p1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=multiprocess_function)
p1.start
```

In the above code snippet, I am starting a new infinite loop process (on a separate core (say #2)). Within this function, I launch 100 threads. Will the threads run on the same core #2 or it will run on the main python core?

Also, how many threads can you run on one core?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All threads run within the process they started from. In this case, the process `p1`.

With regard to how many threads you can run in a process, you have to keep in mind that in CPython, only *one thread at a time can be executing Python bytecode*. This is enforced by the Global Interpreter Lock ("GIL"). So for jobs that require a lot of calculations it is generally better to use processes and not threads.

If you look at the documentation for `concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor`, by default the number of worker threads that it uses is five times the amount of physical processors. That seams to be a reasonable amount for the kinds of workloads that the `ThreadPoolExecutor` is meant for.